# Why do DynamicGeoGraphics and GeoGraphics not generate the same relief map?

Tags: geographics, dynamic

Documentation indicates that DynamicGeoGraphics takes the same options as GeoGraphics, except with respect to projections. Thus, one might expect that given the same options both should produce the same map perhaps not quite projected the same, but with DynamicGeoGraphics being able to be zoomed in and out.

Can anyone explain why the call to DynamicGeoGraphics fails to generate the same relief map as does GeoGraphics?

```
 GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[{GrayLevel[0], Thickness[Large]}],Polygon[Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"NewYork", "UnitedStates"}]]},  GeoBackground -> GeoStyling["ReliefMap"]]

 DynamicGeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[{GrayLevel[0], Thickness[Large]}],Polygon[Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"NewYork","UnitedStates"}]]}, GeoBackground -> GeoStyling["ReliefMap"]]
```

Rather than creating the ReliefMap of the former, it generates a map of an entirely different style with labeling. Likewise, using GeoStyling["Satellite"] doesn't generate a satellite image, but rather the same map as when setting Geostyling["ReliefMap"].  It would seem the documention requires further explanation.

Comment: Unfortunately this is incomplete behaviour in DynamicGeoGraphics. I'm unaware of an easy solution, unfortunately.